# Which sorting is efficient to sort data from ascending order to descending order?

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures

I want to sort a set of data using C implementation. I wonder which sorting is efficient and best case in time-complexity. Note that, the data are in ascending order only. I want to sort it to descending order. Which one is more efficient & least efficient and why?
Can anybody explain it with reason?

Comment: I suggest you look at the comparison table at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms, and take your pick!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In that specific case you don't have to use a sorting algorithm as such. For example you can just swap the `i`th element with the `n - i`th element:

```
for(i = 0; i < size/2; ++i)
{
    tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[size - 1 - i];
    arr[size - 1 - i] = tmp;
}
```

This has always the complexity `O(n/2)`. I dont't think that there is a much faster way. Apart from just reading the data in the other direction of course.